# Почему не работает цикл с fread для обработки бинарного файла.?

Tags: c, файлы, циклы, структуры, while

Программа обрабатывает бинарный файл, было замечено, что результат выводит не тот, что должен. Был сделан тестовый вывод, просто посмотреть сколько раз выполняется цикл while. Вопрос в том, почему он выполняется 1 раз, хотя в файле, на основе которого "строился" бинарный -  содержалось  три записи. ( Если что, бинарный файл строился в другой программе и насколько было проверено - построен он так, как нужно). В общем, вопрос в том, почему while срабатывает один раз. И дело все таки в бинарнике или ошибка где-то в этом коде?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "abitur.h"

void usage()
{
    printf("Usage: [input filename] [number of points]\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        usage();
        return 1;
    }

    int pts = atoi(argv[2]);
    int n = 0;
    abitur p;
    FILE* inp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (!inp)
    {
        perror("Can't open file");
        return 2;
    }

    while (fread(&p, sizeof(p), 1, inp) != 0)
    {
        n = n + 1;
    }

    printf("%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

```
    #ifndef __abitur_h__
    #define __abitur_h__
    typedef struct
    {
    char fam[100];
    char init[50];
    char pol[10];
    int school;
    char medal[10];
    int bm;
    int bf;
    int br;
    char zachet[10];
    }
    abitur;
    #endif
```

программа созд. бин файла

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include "abitur.h"
    void usage() {
    printf("Usage: input file output file\n");
    }
     
    int readabitur(FILE* inp, abitur* p)
    {
    return fscanf(inp, "%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%d\t%[^\t]\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%[^\t]\n",
    p->fam, p->init, p->pol, &p->school, p->medal, &p->bm, &p->bf, &p->br, p->zachet) ==9;
    }
     
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    if (argc!=3)
    {
    usage();
    return 1;
    }
     
    abitur p;
    FILE* inp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE* out = fopen(argv[2], "w");
     
    if(!(out&&inp))
    {
    perror("Can't open");
    return 2;
    }
    while (readabitur(inp, &p))
    {
    fwrite(&p,sizeof(p),1,out);
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

исходный файл - таблица с тремя строками и 9-ю столбцами( кол-во строк не очень важно)

размер исходного - 86 байт
размер бин. файла - 200

OS Unix (ubuntu)

бин файл
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, хотелось бы посмотреть как минимум на определение `abitur`. Узнать размер имеющегося файла, если не его содержимое. И вы открываете его без указания бинарности - но не упоминаете, в какой операционной системе это делаете...

Comment: @Harry    OS Unix(ubuntu),

Comment: @Harry #ifndef __abitur_h__
#define __abitur_h__
typedef struct
{
char fam[100];
char init[50];
char pol[10];
int school;
char medal[10];
int bm;
int bf;
int br;
char zachet[10];
}
abitur;
#endif

Comment: Внесите лучше это все в сам вопрос... И - какой реально размер в байтах у читаемого файла?

Comment: @Harry 
Исходный файл:
таблица с тремя строками и 9-ю столбцами 

размер бинарника - 200 байт
размер исходного -  86 байт

Comment: размер файла очень маленький (89). размер структуры = 200 байт. Он у вас только ноль раз должен считать.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Я, честно говоря, думал, что поскольку в изначальном файле три записи, то в структуре также должно быть три "блока" и поэтому выполниться оно должно будет три раза... В конце-концов, я например, пытался сделать условие, чтоб мол он посчитал кол-во полей, подходящих определенному условию и он все равно выводил 1, Хотя, таких полей 2 штуки. Поэтому, сложилось впечатление, что он обрабатывает только первый блок и потом почему-то прекращает выполнение.

Comment: невозможно ответить, так как нет файла И нет программы, которая это записывала.

Comment: У вас записывающая программа использовала ту же структуру данных `struct abitur` или всё же нет. Судя по комментариям и вашим словам в оригинальном бинарном файле у вас `char *fam; char *init;` (ну не прямо указатели, а просто строки произвольной длины), то есть не записи, а больше на поток похоже. `sizeof(struct abitur) == 196` (если я ничего не упустил), так что 1 раз, одна запись, да. Возможно вы не понимаете, что такое **запись** в терминах бинарных файлов (вот где Паскаль был хорош!). На будущее, программирование — в основном это про структуры данных, плохо, что этому не учат.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Программу я прикрепил, а файл - там просто таблица, разделенная tab, 3 строки - 9 столбцов.

Comment: @0andriy Я вас услышал, возможно, вы действительно правы, но вроде, я уже обрабатывал такими же методами другие таблицы, и там все работало, так как я и представлял и структура разделялась на отдельные записи, поэтому то, что здесь это не работает, меня крайне удивило

Comment: Ну покажите вывод `hexdump -C <ваш_бинарный_файл>`. Всё сразу станет ясно. (Если нет `hexdump`, можно так `od -aX -tx1 ...`)

Comment: когда вы записываете, нет команды `fclose`. В файл не должно быть ничего записано. И при чтении тоже нет `fclose`.

Comment: @0andriy я добавил

Comment: размер файла равен одной структуре. значит в функцию записи этого файла добавьте `fclose`. Тогда что-нибудь запишется.

Comment: @AlexGlebe так, как я понимаю, он записывает, проблема видимо в том, что почему то исходный файл, где несколько записей преобразовывается в структуру с одной сплошной записью...
грубо говоря, если  в исходном файле 1-a 2-b 3-c, то  в бинарном 1- abc

Comment: @AlexGlebe, это не страшная ошибка, ОС закроет файл, хотя может потерять последний буфер (как правило до размера 1 страницы, что часто составляет 4096 байт).

Comment: В программе записи вы пишете `"w"`, а должно быть `"a"` или `"a+"`. В конце не забывайте сбрасывать буферы на носитель `man fflush(3)`, и, как правильно отметил @AlexGlebe, закрывайте файлы `man fclose(3)`. В общем, вам читать и читать мануалы, начните с `man fopen(3)`. Ну и перед записью вообще чистите данные структуры, чтобы не было всякого мусора в текстовых полях, не говоря уже о бинарных `man memset(3)`.

Comment: @0andriy я в итоге правильно понимаю, что моя структура вместо преобразования файла 1-a 2-b 3-c в 1-a 2-b 3-c только в бинарном "формате", записывает все в виде 1-abc?

Comment: Понятия не имею, я не вчитывался в ваш код. Но лажа в бинарном файле очевидна.